# switch style C# construct with double range cases

Tags: c#, double, switch-statement

I'm trying to come up with the best way of doing some kind of switch style selection on a double to find out what range it is in.  Something like this:

```
double a = 1.1;
switch(a)
{
case: (0.0, 1.6)
 return 1;
case: (1.6, 2.337)
 return 2;
case: (2.337, 3.2974)
 return 3;
default:
  return -1;
}
```

Obviously in this example, one value in the range would have to be non-inclusive, but you get my drift.  Any Ideas?

Edit, the ranges are not necessarily integral.

EDIT 2:
I'm actually dealing with radians and finding out which of 12 ranges a point is in.  I ended up doing this:

```
double pi = Math.PI;
double[] zones = new double[] {
        0, pi/6, pi/3, pi/2,
        2*pi/3, 5*pi/6, pi, 7*pi/6,
        4*pi/3, 3*pi/2, 5*pi/3, 11*pi/6
    };

for (int i = 0; i < 11; i++)
{
    if (radians > zones[i] && radians <= zones[i + 1])
    {
        return i + 1;
    }
}
```

I started to do an binary search type if-else, but it was going to get too messy.

Comment: And what is the problem with multiple what ifs?

Comment: One obvious pitfall is that you're planning to perform a comparison for equality on a digital representation of floating-point numbers.

Comment: For this example you could just use `Math.Round()` :)

Comment: Are the intervals always the same size?  Is there ever a situation where the intervals overlap?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention the ranges were not integral.

Comment: @PhilBrown how many ranges are there?  If there are thousands, then you might want to invest a little effort into a binary search, which would give better performance than a linear search.

Comment: If that's what you're doing then why not simply multiply the number by six, divide it by pi, and round off to an integer appropriately?

Comment: @Eric Lipper:  You're a genius, I don't now why I didn't think about that.

Comment: Once again illustrating a point I make frequently: **try asking the question you actually need answered** rather than asking a question about your assumed solution. By asking a question about evaluating ranges you might have missed out on a solution that doesn't involve ranges at all.

Comment: @Eric, While I agree with your point, I didn't miss out on a solution.  I had encountered this same issue before where the ranges were not uniform but didn't have time to stack it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The following is ideally suited to adjacent ranges, since you only need to write the range limits once:

```
double a = 1.1;

if (a < 0.0) {
    // Too low
    return -1;
} else if (a < 1.6) {
    // Range [0.0, 1.6)
    return 1;
} else if (a < 2.337) {
    // Range [1.6, 2.337)
    return 2;
} else if (a < 3.2974) {
    // Range [2.337, 3.2974)
    return 3;
} else {
    // Too high
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: +1 If the solution needs to be scalable, this approach could be modified to use a binary search, by storing the range definition in an array.  Then you'd have O(log n) rather than O(n).

Comment: Indeed, I started coding my if-then as such but realized it would get messy.

Comment: Of course, I have answered according to the scale suggested by the question. This style should be fine for a handful of ranges. Anything more and you would be better off with a data-driven refactoring (allowing, for example, for the binary search suggested by @phoog)

Answer (score 3):

This is probably over engineering but you could create a `Range` Class with Min and Max values and a Callback Function.

Then just create all the Ranges with respective min, and max values and callback and add them to an IEnumerable.

Use LINQ to find out the correct range:

```
range = Ranges.First(r => r.MinValue <= value and r.MaxValue > value);
```

Then just call the range callback.

Answer (score 1):

Just round up

```
double a = 1.1;
if(d < 0.0)
  return -1;
else
  return (int)Math.Ceiling(a);
```

Comment: Ok, that changes the scenario a bit. I just assumed they were. But it seems Daniel has a nice solution.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will do what you want to do with a nice syntactic structure. Please adjust visibilities and comparisons according to your purposes:

```
public static class Range
{
    public interface ISwitchable
    {
        void SetDefault(Action defaultStatement);
        void Execute();
    }

    public interface ISwitchable<T>: ISwitchable
        where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        T Value { get; set; }
        void AddCase(ICase<T> caseStatement);
    }

    public class Switchable<T> : ISwitchable<T>
        where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        private readonly IList<ICase<T>> _caseStatements = new List<ICase<T>>();
        private Action _defaultStatement;

        #region ISwitchable<T> Members

        public T Value { get; set; }

        public void AddCase(ICase<T> caseStatement)
        {
            _caseStatements.Add(caseStatement);
        }

        public void SetDefault(Action defaultStatement)
        {
            _defaultStatement = defaultStatement;
        }

        public void Execute()
        {
            foreach (var caseStatement in _caseStatements)
                if ((caseStatement.Min.CompareTo(Value) <= 0) && (caseStatement.Max.CompareTo(Value) > 0))
                {
                    caseStatement.Action();
                    return;
                }

            _defaultStatement();
        }

        #endregion
    }

    public interface ICase<T>
        where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        T Min { get; set; }
        T Max { get; set; }

        Action Action { get; set; }
    }

    public sealed class Case<T>: ICase<T>
        where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        #region ICase<T> Members

        public T Min { get; set; }

        public T Max { get; set; }

        public Action Action { get; set; }

        #endregion
    }

    public static ISwitchable<T> Switch<T>(T value)
        where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        return new Switchable<T>();
    }
}

public static class SwitchableExtensions
{
    public static Range.ISwitchable<T> Case<T>(this Range.ISwitchable<T> switchable, T min, T max, Action action)
        where T: IComparable<T>
    {
        switchable.AddCase(new Range.Case<T>{ Min = min, Max = max, Action = action });
        return switchable;
    }
    public static void Default(this Range.ISwitchable switchable, Action action)
    {
        switchable.SetDefault(action);
        switchable.Execute();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Range.Switch(10)
            .Case(0, 3, () => Console.WriteLine("Between 0 and 3"))
            .Case(3, 7, () => Console.WriteLine("Between 3 and 7"))
            .Default(() => Console.WriteLine("Something else"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with a `switch`.

```
if(a >= 0 && a < 1) return 1;
else if(a < 2) return 2;
```

etc.

Alternatively, you could write up a class to hold minval, maxval, and outputval, then just iterate over those possibilities and return the outputval that matches.

Comment: No, I mean your test ranges overlap.  `a==1` satisfies both your statements.

Comment: And now it returns `2` for `a < 0` :)

Comment: No. Nothing you can do after those two lines will negate the fact that `a < 0` will yield `2`. You either need to make it `else if (a > 1 && a < 2) return 2;` or just get rid of `a < 0` at the top, like I do :)

Comment: I get that, I was just saying "use this paradigm" rather than "this is the exact set of code you need"